# Where is the command line in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, command-line

i'm having trouble trying to find the command line to type "dir" and then "bcc32 firsprog.c" so I can compile a program that I made called "firstprog.c" using BCC32 C compiler. I'm using Windows 8 and can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Isn't it amazing we still call it the **MS DOS** command line? There is no MS DOS...

Answer (score 2):

1. From the Desktop Mode:
   Move the mouse cursor to the exact lower left corner until the desktop shortcuts menu appears. Select either Command Prompt or Command Prompt (Admin). The latter runs as a local administrator.
2. From the Charms Bar:
   Move your mouse to the upper right corner until the Charms Bar pops out. Select Apps from the list and type “cmd” in the search box. Click on cmd from the search results.
3. From the Run Command Line:
   Follow the steps to show the “run” command line. Type “cmd” to access the DOS environment.
4. From the Metro UI:
   If you have installed Visual Studio Express (beta), you will see a Developer Command Prompt in one tile group.

Answer (score 0):

Because I do not like to move the mouse that much:

On the desktop: WinKey + R then type `cmd` + `<Enter>`

On the  Metro UI: WinKey + X and select `command prompt` or `command prompt (Admin)`

Comment: ahh thanks iv found it, seems my uni content is outdated because they are still calling it MS DOS that's why I couldn't find it.

Comment: I was a little tempted to answer the question with "There is no MS-DOS on Windows 8; it is compatible." But that would not have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The MS-DOS command line is still `COMMAND.COM` as it was in previous i386 versions of WIndows, although [that may not be what you want…](https://superuser.com/a/319970/101850)